# How to read the date from date time object?

Tags: python

I have a datetime object which looks like the following:

```
2020-04-08 11:23:19-05:00
```

How can I read just the date part from here? For example: 2020-04-08

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime

Comment: Thanks! I could read the date using this.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a string of this format you can just split on whitespace

`dateString.split(" ")[0]`

where `dateString` is your input string

Answer (score 1):

```
myDateTime = datetime.now() #you get a datetime object
myDate = myDateTime.date() #you get a date object
print myDate               #print your date object
2016-05-11
```

Answer (score 1):

```
datetime_object.date().isoformat()
```

This creates a string that looks like you want it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have that date set to a variable, such as `time_and_date`, you would use `time_and_date[0, 9] = date` to select the first 9 characters which are the date. the first '2' is the 0, and the '8' is the 9. You can also change this to select the time.